# Cross domain issue loading an iFrame with javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-domain

I have a script that reads URLs from a txt file, then puts each URL into one iframe as a source, loading the frame with new source one after another. I do this to count loading time of each url that is in my list. Here's my code:

```
$.get("test.txt", function (data) {
        var array = data.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/) 
        var beforeLoad = (new Date()).getTime();    
        var loadTimes = [];
            var beforeTimes = [];               
        $('#frame_id').on('load', function () {                                 
            beforeTimes.push(beforeLoad);
            loadTimes.push((new Date()).getTime()); 
            $('#frame_id').attr('src', array.pop());
                $.each(loadTimes, function (index, value) { 
                    var result = (value - beforeTimes[index]) / 1000;
                        if (result < 0) {
                            result = result * (-1);
                        }   
                    $("#loadingtime" + index).html(result);
                    beforeLoad = value;
                });
        }).attr('src', array.pop());
    });
```

My problem is, when I get a URL that has iframe protection (same origin), my script crashes and it wont display any loading time values. After a lot of research I found a way to load 'same origin' URLs into frames by using the AnyOrigin website. I tested the code from that site and it worked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $.getJSON("http://anyorigin.com/get?url="+"google.lt"+"&callback=?", function(data) {
                var iframe = $("#frame_id")[0];
                var doc = iframe.document;
                if(iframe.contentDocument) {
                    doc = iframe.contentDocument;
                } else if(iframe.contentWindow) {
                    doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
                }
                doc.open();
                doc.writeln(data.contents);
                doc.close();
            });
</script>
        <iframe  id="frame_id"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to combine my code with the one from AnyOrigin, so it would load many URLs from my .txt file, get the loading time of each frame, and bypass the 'same origin' stuff, can anyone help me with that?